# Delete image from firebase storage

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm facing an issue regarding deleting an image from `firebase storage`.
if i upload 10 multiple images to `firebase`. After retrieving multiple images. i deleted all of them. but issue is `firebase` usually delete 7 or 8 images out of 10.
I'm deleting one by one. not all images on one click. For few images, `Firebase storage` thrown exception

> Firebase Storage exception: Object doesn't exist at location

I checked `firebase storage` and `firebase database`. But image exists. i opened the `url` from database and it also shows the image but not deleting from `app`

Here is my `adapter class` code:

```
 final String imageUrl=upload.getUrl();

        final FirebaseUser currentFirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.DATABASE_PATH_UPLOADS);


        holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int pos=holder.getAdapterPosition();
                uploads.remove(pos);

                mDatabase.child(currentFirebaseUser.getEmail().replace(".",",")).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        Upload delete=dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                        if(code.equals(delete.getCode()))
                        {
                            storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(imageUrl);


                            Toast.makeText(context,imageUrl,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                           storageReference.delete().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                    Toast.makeText(context,"Memoir Deleted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                    mDatabase.child(currentFirebaseUser.getEmail().replace(".",",")).child(code).removeValue();
                                }
                            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                    Toast.makeText(context,e.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }
                            });
                        }
notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {


                    notifyDataSetChanged();

                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                        notifyDataSetChanged();


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```